# Delta-v cost of longitudinal plane change correction?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, landing, delta-v, inclination-change

In [a recent question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38571/was-the-lunar-landing-site-always-in-the-same-plane-as-the-cms-orbit/38577), the slow drift of a landing site on a rotating body relative to an orbiter came up.

This would sometimes require a plane change correction when one desires to recover the landing party.

**What would the $\Delta v$ cost of such a maneuver be?**

Some initial considerations:

- The landing site does not uniquely define a plane. While the latitude sets a minimum inclination, the inclination of the orbiter's initial orbit may very well be larger.
- Similarly, an entire family of planes are possible for the pickup orbit. Optimisation would require picking the *closest* one.
- Landing from an equatorial orbit would never require a plane change, and neither will a polar landing.
- When the initial inclination is low and/or the stay is short, the cost is low.
- For all configurations of inclination and latitude, there would be no need for a plane change exactly twice during the body's rotation.
- While the plane change can *usually* be done as a simple impulse, [that's not always optimal](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38150/what-is-the-optimal-inclination-change-strategy). I would imagine calculation just the inclination change angle instead of the velocity change would be simpler

While not exactly a hairy problem, the 3-dimensional geometry is not quite trivial, so it would be nice to have an answer to this for future reference.

Comment: While *not in the spirit of the question*, if launching from Earth, just wait 24 hours for the Earth to rotate back into the same position.  That's what Soyuz 6, 7, and 8 did.  Launched each 24 hours, 6 took movies of the attempted docking of 7 and 8.  They then landed at about the same spot in 24 hour intervals.  Zero delta-v required.